# What is random : crng init done

Tags: linux

Can someone explain to me what the above message means? I am developing a Linux block driver and I am attempting to format with ext4. After a few minutes I get this message. I have tried searching other threads but cant find an explanation of what it is. Thanks

Comment: See [random: fix crng_ready()](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10339337/) (and friends). It means the kernel's generator is fully seeded. The latest kernels use ChaCha20 as the RNG, and the seed size is `2*CHACHA20_KEY_SIZE`.

Answer (score 12):

tl;dr: The kernel's random-number generator is ready to generate random numbers that are unpredictable enough for serious cryptographic use.

In some systems, something at boot time (e.g. starting sshd) waits for this, this happens frequently when switching an embedded system to OpenSSL 1.1. You can fix that with tools like egd or rng-tools, or hardware randomness support, or tweaking things so the rest of bootup doesn't wait on that something to complete.

Backstory:

Pseudo-random number generators are deterministic algorithms, so with enough output (and/or some knowledge of the internal state, or good guesses about it) an attacker can predict the future output. This is Really Bad if some of that output is going to be e.g. a secret cryptographic key.

For a long time, the Linux kernel has had code to extract some true randomness ("entropy") from unpredictable events (arrival time of network packets, user input, etc.), using math we're not expected to understand, and the resultant randomness is made available with /dev/random. If you read from /dev/random it will give you unpredictable random numbers up until this randomness is exhausted, then you have to wait for the kernel to extract more. /dev/urandom will give you the same random numbers, but if the true randomness runs out, it will start using a (potentially predictable) algorithm from there. So it will always give you *something*. (Some systems also have hardware support for true randomness e.g. thermal noise).

But it turns out, for cryptographic purposes, you don't need an unending supply of true randomness. If you start with enough true randomness to get a strong cryptographic key, you can then encrypt (say) an unending string of zeroes. An attacker cannot predict that output without knowing the key (if they can, the encryption you're using is broken, and you've already lost, regardless of how good your randomness is).

So the kernel will collect some randomness from the rest of the system at bootup, until it has enough to generate a good crypto key, then it can generate unpredictable random numbers forever.

Now there's a system call getrandom(), OpenSSL 1.1 uses this to seed its random number generators by default, and that system call will not return until the system has collected enough randomness.